# seam-gen, netbeans and completion

Tags: java, netbeans, seam, facelets, netbeans6.5

How can I make [seam-gen](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1BETA2/reference/en/html/gettingstarted.html) work with [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) 6.5 so that completion of tags (s:, ui:, rich:, ...) works? In the free-form project that seam-gen creates, this does not seam to work. If I create a standard NetBeans web application (File -> New Project), completion does work though.

Thanks,
m.

Answer (score 1):

check your netbeans log. it's propobly facelet parser crashing on richaces taglib. i had this problem with RF v3.2.2, older release worked fine.